# why numpy allows mixed datatypes but docs say that it cannot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a general question but no one is able to give me answer of that i did lot of search in official docs of python and other sources such as bootcamp and datacamp.

Issue is that i have read every where that numpy does not support hetrogenous data types ([OFFICIAL DOCS](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/whatisnumpy.html))

But, when i write the code below it works fine. So, if numpy does not support heterogenous data types then why coding allows??

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(["hello", 3, 4, 5])

print(a)
```

Above statements execute successfully.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation where it says it doesn't support heterogeneous datatypes?

Comment: When I try to run the code you asked about, the numbers were converted to strings.
So the data type of the instance of the array you create is homogenous.

Comment: There is a single data type their, `'<U5'`.

Comment: @yanziselman I think we found the same thing, see my answer

Comment: @RvdV please read here 2nd bullet is telling that it does not support the homogenous data types. 

https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/whatisnumpy.html

Comment: @RvdV it's the *whole point* of numpy. Here's [the Array API reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html), it states "All ndarrays are homogeneous: every item takes up the same size block of memory, and all blocks are interpreted in exactly the same way. How each item in the array is to be interpreted is specified by a separate data-type object, one of which is associated with every array. In addition to basic types (integers, floats, etc.), the data type objects can also represent data structures."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes I know it does, your explanation is very nice! I just thought for completion of the question it'd be good to have it linked

Comment: There's a difference between allowing you to input mixed types, and producing an array with with mixed dtype.  You started with a mixed list, and  ended with a string dtype array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A numpy array has a Declared Type (`dtype`). All elements in the array have to comply with that type or have to be coerced in it. Full stop.

Simply some types are more *tolerant*: if you use a floating point type, most integer values (except for the largests ones) will easily be stored, while the opposite would be wrong. Or you can even use an `object` dtype which allows you to store any Python value, including lists, or dicts.

```
arr = np.array((1, 2.5, 'foo'), dtype=object)
print(type(arr[0]), type(arr[1]), type(arr[2]))
```

gives:

```
<class 'int'> <class 'float'> <class 'str'>
```

The downside is that it does not make sense to use a numpy array here, because you will not be able to use vectorized operation over it...

---

After @juanpa.arrivillaga'great comment, I shall try to go one step further in explaining what happens in `numpy`. `numpy` normally stores *raw* data so that they can be directly used by C routines highly speeding up processing (what is called *vectorizing* in `numpy` idiom). The `dtype` attribute is by construction common to all the elements of a ndarray, and if often a numeric (C) type. For example a numpy array will easily store and process fixed size integers (`int32` or `int64`). In that case, each *slot* in the array will store the number as a 4 (resp 8) bytes integer, while a python integer is a multi-precision number.

What happens with the `object` dtype, is that the array will actually contain *references* (think of it as an address) to any python object.

Comment: To be pedantic, the array doesn't actually store Python objects. `dtype=object` basically means "references (pointers) to CPython objects". And you have to be careful with `type(arr[i])` since that will return the *boxed type*. Of course, all Python objects work this way, as everything is a "reference to an object"... but there is a subtlety here when thinking about numpy.

Comment: Sir you mean to say that numpy has by default dtype ??

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi I don't think that is what this is saying... although what do you mean "by default dtype", exactly?

Comment: sir i actually want to say is that does numpy stores all data types in a one data type?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: thanks for the precision. I am afraid it will be difficult for me to improve my answer with it yet keeping it simple... I shall try anyway...

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi that is what the documentation states, as you've noted in your question, numpy arrays are homogeneous.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir so much ! Now i have got your point...

Comment: Bundle of thanks for so much explanation. Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I tried it out and actually it is homogeneous! Check this out:

```
>>> np.array(["hello", 1, 2, 3])
  array(['hello', '1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U5')
```

What we see here is the type is `U` for Unicode (https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html#numpy.dtype.kind), with length 5 or less. So all the integers got converted to unicode/string type, making the array homogeneous!

Trying to force it to `int` will throw an error:

```
np.array(["hello", 1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

Comment: Sir you mean to say that by default numpy treat every thing as a Unicode?? Am i right??

Comment: It will try to coerce the data to a type that accomodates all data, in this case strings. `x = np.array(['hello', 1, 2, 3, float])` will be of `object` dtype and it probably stores a reference to the python object for each element or something like that. You can see with `sys.getsizeof` how all these different arrays take up different amount of space.

Comment: I don't know, but I think that it will try to find the most specific data type that can fit all inputs. If it's only ints in your list it will be int, but since there is a string in the list it falls back to string, since it can convert int to string but not the other way around